# Background-image missing from my php/ css page

Tags: php, html, css, image, background

I changed my HTML pages to PHP and I think it got broken somewhere. My background image is not displayed on the PHP page but on the HTML page. But I want it in PHP for my project. I'm using the same CSS stylesheet.
PHP code:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<header>

<nav>
    <div class = "logo">
        <h1>
            <a href="index.php">...</a>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">...</a>
        <a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION["useruid"])) {
                echo "<a href=#>Logged in</a>";
                echo "<a href=includes/logout.inc.php>Logout</a>";

            }
        else {
            echo "<a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>

    <main>
        <section>
            <h3>...</h3>
            <p>...</p>
            <a href="signup.php" class="btnone">Sign Up</a>
        </section>
    </main>

</header>

</body>
```

CSS code:

```
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("/php/images/ta.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCmWw.png)

Comment: Where exactly is your background image stored?

Comment: @AHaworth it is stored in the images folder, I put the screenshot of it as "workspace" in the post. You can check for a better idea

Comment: Hi - the image you attached didn't show what's in the images folder - perhaps you named it wrong, perhaps something else ..  That's what @AHaworth was asking

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the wrong path. Add either `.` or remove `/` from the `background-image` field. Like this:

```css
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("./php/images/ta.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

or

```css
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("php/images/ta.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I tried this even before but doesn't seem to work. But the same CSS linked to the HTML document is displaying the required image. The problem happens only in PHP. both documents are linked to the same CSS. I don't have any use with HTML documents but just to check if the problem occurs I still have it and it doesn't in HTML file. So, the problem is only with the PHP file.

Comment: I checked this on my pc ( macOS Monteray version 12) and it seems to be working. In your case is only the image not loading in PHP, or any other CSS styling is also not working?

Comment: only the background image isn't working. The rest of the CSS styling works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The path needs to be relative to the css.

```css
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("../images/ta.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```